# React ajax call when button onClick event using hooks

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    email: ""
  });
  function handleClick() {
    const res = axios.get("url");
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    handleClick();
  })

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        Hello {contact.fName} {contact.lName}
      </h1>
      <p>{contact.email}</p>

      <input name="fName" placeholder={contact.fName} />
      <input name="lName" placeholder={contact.lName} />
      <input name="email" placeholder={contact.email} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I set initial state with empty string but I am trying to update input attributes with data from external source whenever user clicks submit button.

I heard I need to use useEffect method to api call in react, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you're going to update the data on the button click, then you can use a count mechanism, a separate variable to keep track of the count.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1 )}>Submit</button>


 async function handleClick() {
    const res = await axios.get("url");
    setContact(res.data);
  }

useEffect(() => {
  handleClick();
}, [contact, count]);
```